# Call Native android signals using phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova, android-sdk-2.3

Hi everyone am new to android and developed projects on c, dot net frameworks and python. I have to develop application for android and iPhone tablets. Currently I have to write application for android and have two options.

1) Use java and android sdk
2) Use Phonegap

I would love to use Phone-gap because it's seems pretty much easy as I am familiar with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But that's not my limitation as I have used jav with E-clips earlier. much better hint is single app for android and Iphone.

My question is if phone-gap will work for me. what I need to start my app on start-up without showing desktop and always on top. and read screen on/off actions. I have crafted kiosk and installed 10.1" android 4.1 tablet. I have to develop app to give it a POS look. My app should start as early as my device boot and always remain on TOP unless explicitly closed.

Any suggestion will be helpful for me as I am new and have only created hello world app on both.